# 'Error de escucha en el prefijo 'http://localhost:8080/pdf/' porque entra en conflicto con un registro existente en el equipo.'

Tags: c#, windows-forms

El error es que cuando tengo abierto el pdf en el navegador y quiero volverlo abrir nuevamente sin a ver cerrado el primero me  da este error, ESTOY EN C# WINDOWS FORM

Error de escucha en el prefijo 'http://localhost:8080/pdf/' porque entra en conflicto con un registro existente en el equipo.

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp16
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        byte[] DondeSeGuardaElPdfEnByte;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();

            listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:8080/pdf/");
            listener.Start();//ERROR AQUI
            IAsyncResult result = listener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(ListenerCallback), listener);

            // ponemos el documento en el arreglo
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            Document Documento_Pdf_Marsys = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 36, 36, 36, 85);
            PdfWriter pdfWrite = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Documento_Pdf_Marsys, ms);

            iTextSharp.text.Rectangle Page = Documento_Pdf_Marsys.PageSize;
            Documento_Pdf_Marsys.Open();

            /**********************************************************/
            Documento_Pdf_Marsys.Add(new Paragraph("Mi documento"));
            /*********************************************************/

            Documento_Pdf_Marsys.Close(); // SE CIERRA EL DOCUMENTO

            //TRATO DE RECUPERAR EL PDF PERO NO SE SI ESTO SIRVA

            DondeSeGuardaElPdfEnByte = ms.ToArray();
           System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://localhost:8080/pdf/");
        }

        private void ListenerCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)ar.AsyncState;
            HttpListenerContext context = listener.EndGetContext(ar);
            HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
            HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
            if (DondeSeGuardaElPdfEnByte != null)
            {
                response.ContentLength64 = DondeSeGuardaElPdfEnByte.Length;
                System.IO.Stream output = response.OutputStream;
                output.Write(DondeSeGuardaElPdfEnByte, 0, DondeSeGuardaElPdfEnByte.Length);
                output.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

lo que busco es abrir el pdf aunque ya este abierto por que hasta horita crea el pdf pero si esta abierto se me cierra el programa podrían ayudarme de favor

Answer (score 0):

Parece que el puerto 8080 esté en uso por alguna otra aplicación. Sería conveniente extraer un "netstat -anbo" desde cmd (accediendo como administrador), como se desarrolla en [este post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58585326/failed-to-listen-on-prefix-http-localhost5041-because-it-conflicts-with-an).